# How do you change versions of gcc on windows?

Tags: gcc, mingw, g++

I've been using g++ 4.8.1, mingw. Now, I've just updated to 6.3.0, however when I use g++ in command prompt it still seems to use the older version. How do you change between versions on windows?

Answer (score 0):

Look in the system PATH variable for the path that leads to your mingw install.
If there is more than one path that leads to a mingw install present delete the old ones and if you havent allready create a new entry for the new install.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser and thank you for your answer. Please could you expand your answer to show what the item in the PATH Variable may look like?

Comment: @Steven Davison Sorry didnt have the time for it and i assumed since he seems to have been using mingw that he would be familliar with environment variables

Comment: no worries. It was from a question completeness point of view. the answer was in my review list. :)

Comment: @StevenDavison oh i did not know that such a feature existed. thx for pointing that out to me ^^